# Running Node.Js and Apache on the same server and different domain

Tags: node.js, wordpress, port, centos7, vps

I have a web server which contains the files for both domains
1-exemple.id and 2-exemple.info.

I want to run Wordpress on "1" and NodeJs for "2".

1" points to the directory /home/xxxxx/public_html and 2" points to the directory /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxxx.info.

The issue here is that I have tried a couple of times to get this working. I used iptables for forwarding traffic from port 3000(NodeJs) to 80. This made it worse as the NodeJs server is now showing on both domains 1" and 2".

Looking forward to hear your suggestions.

Please note: I am using CentOs7

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forward traffic to a different port you need to configure Apache as a proxy in your virtual hosts file:

```
ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
```

Make sure you activate the proxy modules for Apache:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```